# group list facebook sdk on android not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk

im trying to get the users group list.

before i ask how to extract that information from the "response" this is my code:

permissions:

```
this.login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
login.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_groups", "friends_groups"));
```

request:

```
Request share = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "/me/groups", new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
            Log.d("getting groups", go.toString());

        }
    });
```

first of all a few issues:
1. the log.d line not showing. meaning the app dosent get to that call back.

1. is the code ok?
2. how to handle the response, meaning how to extract the information?
3. thank you !

Comment: Did you also do share.executeAsync()? Until you call execute, the request doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I didn't. I have an example that works with request.newmerequest. and there is no execute. I'll try. Any way, how do I handle the response? Thanx

Comment: The response will go to your callback, so ... you're already handling it.